# Grey Out/Overlay/Blur out NavigationBar when wrappedValue GeometryReader PopUp is activated SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I stuctured a view like this with the goal to blur out the View on a Button click, that works fine if $enableSheet gets set to true! But the NavigationBar and the NavigationBarTitle stays unblured, which looks kinda odd and defeats the purpose...
So how can I grey out/blur out/Overlay the NavigationBar?
I do not want to hide it just make it unusable as long as the pop up shows

```
struct ContentView: View {
//...
var body: some View {
ZStack{
 VStack{}
 .blur(radius: $enableSheet.wrappedValue ? 1 : 0)
            .overlay(
                $enableSheet.wrappedValue ? Color.black.opacity(0.6) : nil
            )
            if $enableSheet.wrappedValue {
                 GeometryReader { gr in
//..code
}}
}
.navigationBarItems
.navigationBarTitle
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying blur upon `ContentView`, try to apply the blur upon `NavigationView`. (You can put the blur-view and navigation-view in a ZStack if needed for that.) And then you can expose the `enableSheet` (and relevant variables) into environment to be used by any view down the line.